# Swagger documentation for facebook graph api

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, swagger

Can we build a swagger definition in a json format for  facebook graph api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, it has already be done by Kin Lane the API Evangelist.
His work his available on the [API Stack website](http://theapistack.com/) (search Facebook in the page), all files are in a [github repository](https://github.com/api-stack/api-stack/tree/gh-pages/_data/facebook).

Comment: That website is now spam and the github repo is gone